# How do I set the correct Content-Type header for the different browsers?

Tags: http-headers, content-type, config, apache

I'm running an Apache server to host my websites. They are all written in XHTML5 so I **WANT** to serve them as `application/xhtml+xml`.

The default on Apache is to serve pages as `text/html`.

Is there a configuration that I can put at the bottom on my config file that will set the response header `Content-Type` to `application/xhtml+xml` for the browsers that support it, otherwise serve as `text/html` (for < IE9 basically.)

Answer (score 4):

mod_setenvif and mod_headers combined should make that possible.  I'd suggest setting the normal content type for .html files to `application/xhtml+xml` if you want to serve that most of the time.

```
AddType application/xhtml+xml html
```

Then match the clients you want to treat specially and change the Content-Type:

```
BrowserMatch some-regex-matching-old-clients is_old_and_crap
Header edit Content-Type application/xhtml\+xml text/html env=is_old_and_crap
```

---

Failing that it should be trivial too with mod_rewrite.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:User-Agent} some-regex-matching-old-clients
RewriteRule \.html$ - [T=text/html]
```

The rule here is used to match requests for files ending with .html which isn't ideal. The extension could appear before the end (such as `foo.html.en.gz` or not at all (index.html files perhaps). It would be better to use the current value of Content-Type but I believe mod_rewrite runs too early in the request cycle for that to be possible.

Comment: I should note that although it's commendable that you're trying to use the standard content-type here, by varying it based on the User-Agent you're breaking the http standard a little. You should probably add a `Vary: User-Agent` header if the server doesn't do it for you.

Comment: Here is a link backing what noodl suggest about using RewriteEngine: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipapachexhtml/index.html